# Condition for msiexec in quiet mode?

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I have a custom action which pops up a dialog. I would like to suppress the custom action using a condition property if my installer is being run in quiet mode (ie. /q in msiexec). How do you do that?

I know I can use a property:

msiexec /i .msi /qn SUPPRESS_MY_CUSTOM_ACTION=1

and then

use Condition property of:

NOT SUPPRESS_MY_CUSTOM_ACTION

But, it would be better to just be able to know if I'm in quiet mode.

Answer (score 1):

Custom actions scheduled in the execute sequence should seldom have UI.  A rare exception would be an abort, retry, fail  type dialog where a retry could result in a successful installation.  The custom action should check the built in [UILevel property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine if it's appropriate to display a UI.

You probably don't want to suppress the custom action completely as certain default assumptions can probably be done without a UI.   Otherwise you might also want to consider factoring the custom action out into the UI sequence and Execute sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with what Christopher says. But in addition to being able to condition off of `UILevel` (which works in either the action's condition, or inside the action's code itself), there's another approach. Change how you put up your UI from calling something like `MessageBox` directly to instead call `MsiProcessMessage` (with e.g. `INSTALLMESSAGE_USER`) to have Windows Installer show the message box. It will internally handle the equivalent of checking `UILevel`, but note this other approach will not work from a Control Event.